# CoordinatorLayout doesn't show ViewStub child

Tags: android, android-layout, android-coordinatorlayout, viewstub

**CoordinatorLayout doesn't show ViewStub child.**

I try inflate ViewStub but view doesn't showed. Do I have to add some layout behavior or some flag to my ViewStub?

Any ideas?

Below is my layouts:

**activity_main.xml**

```
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:fab="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/application_bar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
            app:title="Test"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            style="@style/MyCustomTabLayout" />

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/view_pager"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/moments_bg"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior" />

    <ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/tutorial"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/tutorial_import"
        android:layout="@layout/tutorial"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

**tutorial.xml**

```
<FrameLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#99000000">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="280dp"
        android:layout_height="300dp"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
        android:background="@drawable/add_moment_oval">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tutorial_desc"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_centerInParent="true"
            android:textColor="@color/default_text_color"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:text="test"/>

        <Button
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tutorial_desc"
            android:textColor="@color/accent"
            android:textSize="14dp"
            android:text="accept"
            android:theme="@style/DashboardButton"
            style="?android:attr/borderlessButtonStyle" />

    </RelativeLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

**MainActivity.java**

```
 @OnClick(R.id.add_button)
    public void onAddButtonClicked(){

        View v = findViewById(R.id.tutorial);

        if (v instanceof ViewStub) {
            ((ViewStub)v).inflate();
        }
    }
```

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this? I am having the same issue

Comment: @JeffThomas Unfortunately, I not found a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Try using `ViewStubCompat` instead of `ViewStub`